# 'DEFAULT' in Amazon Redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

Anyone knows the Redshift equivalent of 'DEFAULT' function used when creating table in Oracle?

E.g.

```
create table customer1
(
  customer_id number,
  customer_name varchar2(20),
  exp_date date DEFAULT to_date('31-dec-2099','dd-mon-yyyy')
)
```

Comment: DEFAULT should work. What is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

The [`CREATE TABLE` documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CREATE_TABLE_NEW.html) shows:

> DEFAULT default_expr
>
> Clause that assigns a default data value for the column. The data type of default_expr must match the data type of the column. The DEFAULT value must be a variable-free expression. Subqueries, cross-references to other columns in the current table, and user-defined functions are not allowed.